# Thailand Mathematics ​contest grade9 problem

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers

let $x$ be a negative real number such that
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x+(\sqrt 2+1)^x=2\sqrt 5$$
find the value of $$(\sqrt 2-1)^x-(\sqrt 2+1)^x$$

attempts
i try to multiply
$$((\sqrt 2-1)^x+(\sqrt 2+1)^x)​((\sqrt 2-1)^x-(\sqrt 2+1)^x)$$

and i dont get the answer

Comment: To format the square root you need a backslash, as in "\sqrt 2"

Comment: thanks for your advice!

Comment: Hint:  square the initial expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x+(\sqrt 2+1)^x=2\sqrt 5 \tag{Given}$$
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x-(\sqrt 2+1)^x=k \tag{Assumed}$$

Adding the two equations yields,
$$2\sqrt 5+k=2(\sqrt 2-1)^x. \tag{1}$$

Subtracting the 2nd equation from the first gives us,
$$2\sqrt 5-k=2(\sqrt 2+1)^x. \tag{2}$$

Now multiply equation (1) by equation (2) to get,
$$20-k^2=4\Bigl(\left(\sqrt 2-1\right)\left(\sqrt 2+1\right)\Bigr)^x=4.$$

Therefore,
$$k=\pm4.$$

Since $x$ is negative,
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x\gt (\sqrt 2+1)^x.$$

Therefore,
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x-(\sqrt 2+1)^x=+4.$$

Comment: @Vasya  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x+(\sqrt 2+1)^x=2\sqrt 5 \tag{Given}$$
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^{2x}+(\sqrt 2+1)^{2x}+2(\sqrt 2-1)^x(\sqrt 2+1)^x=20 \tag{Square}$$

$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x-(\sqrt 2+1)^x=k \tag{The value we want}$$
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^{2x}+(\sqrt 2+1)^{2x}-2(\sqrt 2-1)^x(\sqrt 2+1)^x=k^2 \tag{Square}$$

Note that $2(\sqrt 2-1)^x(\sqrt 2+1)^x=2(1)^x=2 \tag{Difference of two squares}$

The two equations can be rewritten

$$(\sqrt 2-1)^{2x}+(\sqrt 2+1)^{2x}+2=20 \tag{1}$$

$$(\sqrt 2-1)^{2x}+(\sqrt 2+1)^{2x}-2=k^2 \tag{2}$$

Subtracting $(1) - (2)$ gives
$$4=20 -k^2$$

Rearrange

$$k^2=16$$

Therefore,
$$k=\pm4$$

As noted in the other answer,

$$x<0 \Rightarrow (\sqrt 2-1)^x\gt (\sqrt 2+1)^x$$

Therefore,
$$(\sqrt 2-1)^x-(\sqrt 2+1)^x=+4$$